# Can't export a EC2 AMI to another account because the AWS Marketplace OS is obsolete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I'm trying to backup an old instance that I have from one of my accounts that I want to close down so I don't lose that instance. I was thinking in backing up the instance by making it an AMI and then transfer that image to another AWS account which I still have active.

I then started the process of sharing the image with the other aws account that I have and when I want to launch a new EC2 instance using that AMI, I get this error: 
[image]

Then I went to that URL described in the error message to subscribe I get this notification:

[image]

According to what I'm seeing, AWS doesn't offer this version of centos OS, so I was wondering what happens in these cases, is there anything that can be done so I can still create the backup and save it in my other active account?

Comment: Hi @VaTo. Did you get this resolved somehow in the end? I am having a similar issue and not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the data inside your instance, maybe you can try to create a snapshot of the volume and make it available for your other account ?