# Launching AMI with obsolete marketplace AMI : How to OptIn or Upgrade?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have a linux ec2 instance hosting some legacy tools that I need to move to another AWS.   We hoped to do this by making an AMI, sharing it to the other account, bringing up the new instance from the AMI, etc.

The problem:  The instance was built on an AWS marketplace image of Debian - I must opt-in to the terms and conditions (and subscribe) in order to use the image.  However, it is Debian8 (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-5pgbnftzmrgec) which is no longer offered in the marketplace.  Since the base image is no longer offered, I cannot opt in.

Is it possible to just upgrade/update the source instance to Debian 9 or 10 (both are still offered in the marketplace) so that I will be able to accept the T&C?  Or is there some way to tell the AMI itself to use Debian 9 instead?

If not, I am looking at an old style file-based migration, and I was really hoping not to have to get into the guts of this server (it's a legacy integration) just yet.  (It's on the to-do list, I just really wanted to get the migration to our AWS account finished first.)

I found this related question, but the suggested answer does not work - I can create and share the snapshot, even create a volume, but I cannot attach/mount the volume without "accept[ing] terms and subscribe" to the underlying product (Debian 8).
[Can't export a EC2 AMI to another account because the AWS Marketplace OS is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56689874/cant-export-a-ec2-ami-to-another-account-because-the-aws-marketplace-os-is-obso)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You might get a better response at https://www.reddit.com/r/aws since there are a lot of long-term AWS users there.

Comment: Hi @AlexNich. Did you get this resolved in the end? I'm having a similar issue with an obsolete Ubuntu AMI.